# Oracle sort nested query and rownum

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, rownum

i have a query that takes too much. 
It's running a 10g oracle instance.
TABLE_A has 30.000.000 rows.
TABLE_B has 300.000 rows.

```
SELECT A.F1, A.F2, B.F1
  FROM (  SELECT A.F1, A.F2, B.F1
          FROM TABLE_A A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.ID_B = B.ID_B
          WHERE A.F3 = ? AND A.F4 = ?
        ORDER BY B.F1)
 WHERE ROWNUM < 100
```

I tried to create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW TABLE_B_SORTED AS SELECT * FROM TABLE_B ORDER BY F1
```

modifying the query like that

```
SELECT A.F1, A.F2, B.F1
  FROM (  SELECT A.F1, A.F2, B.F1
          FROM TABLE_A A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B_SORTED B ON A.ID_B = B.ID_B
          WHERE A.F3 = ? AND A.F4 = ?
       )
 WHERE ROWNUM < 100
```

but the order is not manteined.

I also tried to modify the query in this way

```
SELECT A.F1, A.F2, T.F1
  FROM (  SELECT A.F1, A.F2, T.F1
          FROM TABLE_A A LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE_B B ORDER BY B.F1 ) T ON A.ID_B = T.ID_B
          WHERE A.F3 = ? AND A.F4 = ?
       )
 WHERE ROWNUM < 100
```

but the order is not manteined.

Any suggestion?

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 8.943  Bytes: 2.871  Cardinality: 99                        
    7 COUNT STOPKEY                      
        6 VIEW MY_SCHEMA. Cost: 8.943  Bytes: 146.247  Cardinality: 5.043                  
            5 SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY  Cost: 8.943  Bytes: 226.935  Cardinality: 5.043              
                4 HASH JOIN OUTER  Cost: 8.881  Bytes: 226.935  Cardinality: 5.043          
                    2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TABLE_A Cost: 8.117  Bytes: 172.725  Cardinality: 4.935      
                        1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX I_TABLE_A Cost: 27  Cardinality: 10.166  
                    3 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE TABLE_B Cost: 758  Bytes: 2.791.520  Cardinality: 279.152
```

Comment: Could you post the EXPLAIN PLAN that this query generates please?

Comment: I guess the reason this query takes so long is the fact that you sort on a column that is left joined. So an index on that column won't help because the sorting must also include those rows that result from an unsuccessful join (resulting in a NULL value in that column). Is a left join really necessary or would a right join do as well? Is the column B.F1 nullable?

Comment: @Codo: unfortunately the B.F1 field is nullable.

Comment: The left join and the nullable column are two major reasons why indicies won't make much of a difference. Oracle will have to completely join the two tables, then sort the result and then take the first 100 rows. It's almost impossible to reorder these three steps. So I can't see any possible shortcut for working with a limited number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should create probably create an ascending index on b.f1 if your query takes too much time.

Additionally if you are performing a LEFT JOIN this means that you may have NULL values in B. Do you want them first or last?

Probably you should better do:

```
   SELECT /*+ first_rows_100 */ -- do not hesitate to use Oracle hints!
          a.f1, a.f2, b.f1
     FROM table_b b
    INNER JOIN table_a a
       ON a.id_b = b.id_b
    WHERE a.f3 = ? and a.f4 = ?
    ORDER BY b.f1 ASC
```

Also, ordering a join source is completely useles (second and third query). JOINing never guarantees that resulting rows keep the order in which they are found in source tables.

Comment: It doesn't seem that the use of /*+ first_rows_100 */ prevent from retrieving more than 100 rows. By executing the query it takes the same time.

I did perform a LEFT JOIN on purpose, i could have null values in TABLE_B.

I'll try to put a sorted index on TABLE_B.

Comment: The sorted index doesn't help!

Comment: @GAS: What indexes do you have on your tables a and b? it seems that the TABLE ACCESS FULL on table B could be skipped if id_b was indexed on that table.

Comment: @Benoit: Shouldn't the hint be /*+ FIRST_ROWS(100) */ ?

Comment: @Codo: Depends on the Oracle version, I believe yours also works with Oracle 10.

Comment: @Benoit: the ID_B field is a PK in TABLE_B and is indexed in TABLE_A, but the ORDER BY for the field TABLE_B.F1 causes a TABLE ACCESS FULL.
I think that the problem is:
1) TABLE_A joins the unsorted TABLE_B
2) the result is sorted out
3) the ROWNUM restriction is then applied